# I am getting SQL Insert syntax error in python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE jongmok(Date text, Jongmok_num int, Jongmok_name text)
```

---

```
"INSERT INTO jongmok(Date, Jongmok_num, Jongmok_name) 
 VALUES(%s, %d, %s);" % (dday, bb, cc))
```

---

> Error msg. cursor.execute(INSERT INTO jongmok(Date, Jongmok_num,
>   Jongmok_name) VALUES(%s, %d, %s);" % (dday, bb, cc))
>
> sqlite3.OperationalError: near ".19": syntax error

### Process finished with exit code 1

--> (dday, bb, cc)

All numbers must be entered only (Character type number is ok, too). 
  
In the create or values statement Regardless of the type, if a character is entered, the following error is displayed.

For reference, the value of "dday" is "2019.11.19 12:38".

**sqlite3.version : '2.6.0'**

What should I fix?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: You must add quotes (`''`) for `text`.

Comment: Use quotes around string values in `valules`. But it is not safety way to put value of formal parameters. Best way to use something like 
`sql=conn.cursor('INSERT INTO jongmok(Date, Jongmok_num, Jongmok_name) VALUES(?, ?,?)`
then
`conn.execute(sql,(dday,bb,cc)`

Comment: @CoderCharmander No, that is not the right suggestion.  The OP should be using a prepared statement here.

Comment: What is the error message?  Also, you may want to rename your `Date` column since `DATE` is sometimes a keyword.

Comment: Use format specifier `%s` instead `%d`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"INSERT INTO jongmok(Date, Jongmok_num, Jongmok_name) VALUES('%s', %d, '%s');" % (dday, bb, cc))
```

To avoid syntax errors generated by inserted text (from `bb` and `cc` in your case) you should use quotes.

Comment: problem solving.Thank you so much.